# How to access limit values (min_value, max_value) in a form field?

Tags: django

How can I use min_value and max_value in a view?

E.g. the Form is defined as:

```
class SomeForm(ModelForm):
    somefield = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=10)
```

And in my view I want to do something like (pseudocode):

```
min_value = somefield.min_value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in your view:

```
someform = SormForm() #you may instantiate differently.
sfield= someform.fields['somefield']
min_value = sfield.min_value
max_value = sfield.max_value
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did and it did not work, but I just found out I did not read the error message properly: 'ChoiceField' object has no attribute 'min_value' - that is my problem... Apologies for this pollution on SO.